# How can I filter a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell beginner, so apologies in advance.

I'm parsing out some HTML values (`<a name="value-to-extract">`) using [HXT](http://adit.io/posts/2012-04-14-working_with_HTML_in_haskell.html) and haskell. I can get a list of `a name=""` `name` values using this:

```
anames <- runX $ parseHtml contents >>> css "a" >>> getAttrValue "name"
```

If I do this:

```
print anames
```

Then it prints this list:

`["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","2H_4_0001","2HCH0001","2HCH0002","2HCH0003","2HCH0004","2HCH0005","2HCH0006","2HCH0007","2HCH0008","2HCH0009","2HCH0010","2HCH0011","2HCH0012","2HCH0013","2HCH0014","2HCH0015","2HCH0016","2HCH0017","2HCH0018","2HCH0019","2HCH0020","2HCH0021","2HCH0022","2HCH0023","2HCH0024","2HCH0025","2HCH0026","2HCH0027","2HCH0028","2HCH0029","2HCH0030","2HCH0031","2H_4_0033"]`

Now I want to remove all the entries that are `""`.

So I try

```
nonEmptyANames <- filter (\s -> s /= "") anames
```

But I get this error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
  Expected type: IO String
    Actual type: [String]
• In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    nonEmptyANames <- filter (\ s -> s /= "") anames
```

I think this is a typing problem, so I try:

```
putStrLn ("type of aname is: " ++ (show (typeOf anames)))
```

And it tells me that the type of `aname` is `[Char]`. If I try the filter command in ghci, it works as expected. What am I missing here?

Comment: The issue is more that `filter` is not monadic...

Comment: Write `let nonEmptyANames = filter (\s -> s /= "") anames`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filter` has signature:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

So it is not monadic. In that case you can use a `let` expression. You should replace `nonEmptyANames <- filter (\s -> s /= "") anames` with:

```
    let nonEmptyANames = filter (\s -> s /= "") anames
```